# Groovy grep + build key value

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a variable holding the following text:

```
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 30
name: muzi
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 20
name: puzi
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
.
.
.
```

What i want to do is to grep the name and messages (every time the messages is related to the name that comes up right after him)

and set it up in data (switch name and messages) for example key value pair
so i would have

```
Data = [
"muzi": 30
"puzi": 20
]
```

And so one.
This is something that i can easily do in powershell but i have no experience in groovy and id love if someone can offer me some help.

Comment: please share your code in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
def lines='''
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 30
name: muzi
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 20
name: puzi
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 11
name: puz
'''.readLines()

//Like this
def messages = lines.findAll{ it=~/^messages:\s+/ }.collect{ it.split(/:\s+/)[1] }
def names = lines.findAll{ it=~/^name:\s+/ }.collect{ it.split(/:\s+/)[1] }
def res = [names,messages].transpose().collectEntries()
println res

//OR like this:
res = lines.findAll{ it=~/^(messages|name):\s+/ }.collect{ it.split(/:\s+/)[1] }.collate(2).collectEntries{[it[1], it[0]]}
println res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiline regexp, which enforces that the two lines are *consecutive*.
See the *negative data* at the beginning of the string.

```
String txt = """
messages: 300
blablablabla
name: zeny
blablablabla
blablablabla
messages: 30
name: muzi
blablablabla

blablablabla
messages: 20
name: puzi
blablablabla
"""

def res = [:]

txt.findAll(/(?ms)^messages: (\d+)$.^name: (\w+)$/) {match, w1, w2 -> res[w2] = w1}

assert res == [muzi:'30', puzi:'20']
```